# input in if condition in python

Tags: python, if-statement, input

Can inputting and checking be done in the same line in python?

Eg) in C we have

```
if (scanf("%d",&a))
```

The above statement if block works if an integer input is given. But similarly,

```
if a=input():
```

Doesn't work in python. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You're wrong about scanf; it returns the number of elements read, and the value of `a` doesn't enter into it.

Comment: The C code will execute the 'then' clause of the `if` both when `a` is successfully read and when the program encounters EOF.  That is not very good C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Python can't do assignment as part of the condition of an `if` statement. The only way to do it is on two lines:

```
a=input()
if a:
    // Your code here
    pass
```

This is by design, as it means that assignment is maintained as an atomic action, independent of comparison. This can help with readability of the code, which in turn limits the potential introduction of bugs.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do it. This was a deliberate design choice for Python because this construct is good for causing hard to find bugs.

see @Jonathan's comment on the question for an example